# How to compare between days or months or year together with momentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Need help with getting the best approach to get the right output status.
I am writing a function purchaseDateChecker which outputs the correct status from a user input, which falls between certain date ranges. I am not getting certain outputs(status), so wondering if this is the correct way to compare days and months or year in momentJS or javascript.

So basically trying to achieve something like this - if a date is **isAfter() or isSame() and between 31days and less than 6 months**

```js
function purchaseDateChecker(dateSelection) {
  var datePeriod = moment(dateSelection, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
    cutOffDate = moment('2015-10-01'),
    todayDate = moment(),
    purchaseDateStatus,
    daysDiff = todayDate.diff(datePeriod, 'days'),
    monthsDiff = todayDate.diff(datePeriod, 'months'),
    yearDiff = todayDate.diff(datePeriod, 'years');

  console.log('purchase date: ' + datePeriod);
  console.log('days difference: ' + daysDiff);
  console.log('mths difference: ' + monthsDiff);
  console.log('years difference: ' + yearDiff);
  console.log('today date: ' + todayDate);

  if (datePeriod.isBefore(cutOffDate) && daysDiff < 61) {
    // Purchased date is before the cut off date or less than 61 days
    purchaseDateStatus = 'purchased before';
  } else if (datePeriod.isAfter(cutOffDate) || datePeriod.isSame(cutOffDate) || daysDiff < 31) {
    // Purchased date is after/the same as cut off date or less than 31 days
    purchaseDateStatus = 'purchased after';
  } else if (datePeriod.isAfter(cutOffDate) || datePeriod.isSame(cutOffDate) || daysDiff < 31 && monthsDiff < 6) {
    // Purchased date is after/the same as cut off date or less than 31 days
    purchaseDateStatus = 'between 31 days 6 months';
  } else if (yearDiff > 6) {
    purchaseDateStatus = 'over 6 years';
  } else if (monthsDiff > 6 || yearDiff < 6) {
    purchaseDateStatus = ' between 6 months and 6 years';
  } else if (datePeriod.isBefore(cutOffDate) || daysDiff < 61 && monthsDiff < 6) {
    purchaseDateStatus = 'between 61 days and 6 months'
  }

  return purchaseDateStatus;
}

console.log(purchaseDateChecker('2015-04-01'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Instead of setting a variable and then returning, why not simply return immediately?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? is this it??  if (datePeriod.isBefore(cutOffDate) && daysDiff < 61) {return 'purchased before';

Answer (score 0):

changed my logic and removed the addition variable to return string

```
if (datePeriod.isBefore(cutOffDate) && daysDiff < 61){
    return dateSelection = 'purchased before';
  }
  else if (datePeriod.isBefore(cutOffDate) && daysDiff > 61 && monthsDiff < 6) {
    // purchased date is before the cut off date or less than 61 days
    return dateSelection = 'between 61 days and 6 months'
  }
  else if (datePeriod.isAfter(cutOffDate) || datePeriod.isSame(cutOffDate) || daysDiff < 31) {
      // purchased date is after/the same as cut off date or less than 31 days
      return dateSelection = 'purchased after';
  }
  else if (datePeriod.isAfter(cutOffDate) || datePeriod.isSame(cutOffDate) || daysDiff > 31 && monthsDiff < 6) {
      return dateSelection = 'between 31 days 6 months';
  }
  else if (monthsDiff > 6 && yearDiff < 6) {
      return dateSelection = 'between 6 months and 6 years';  
  }
  else if (yearDiff > 6) {
    return dateSelection = 'over 6 years';
  }
```